# Grouping dates within a timespan

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to group dates within the same timespan of an hour. However, some dates seems to be excluded. What did I miss? Expected result is `[[date1, date2], [date3], [date4]]`

```
function groupDates(dates) {
  var result = [];
  var intervalStart = dates[0];
  var grp = []
  dates.forEach((d,i) => {
    var diff = d.getTime() - intervalStart.getTime()
    if(diff/1000/60 <= 60) {
      grp.push(d)
    } else { 
      intervalStart = date;
      grp = [d]
      result.push(grp)
    }
  })
  return result
}

console.log(groupDates([new Date('2017-01-01 17:24'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 17:25'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 18:26'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 19:27')]))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ps7m03gv/

Comment: You have an error in your else clause: intervalStart = d, not date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `else` block. You detect that the current group should end, but you discard it before pushing it onto the `result` array.

Move the `result.push(grp)` line to the top of the `else` block, and add an additional `result.push(grp)` after the loop to handle the last group.

```
function groupDates(dates) {
  var result = [];
  var intervalStart = dates[0];
  var grp = [];
  dates.forEach((d,i) => {
    var diff = d.getTime() - intervalStart.getTime();
    if(diff/1000/60 <= 60) {
      grp.push(d);
    } else {
      result.push(grp);
      intervalStart = d;
      grp = [d];
    }
  })
  result.push(grp);
  return result;
}

console.log(groupDates([new Date('2017-01-01 17:24'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 17:25'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 18:26'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 19:27')]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to do *hours level grouping*, try

```
var output = Object.values(inputArr.reduce( function(a,b){
  var date = new Date(b);
  date.setHours( date.getHours(), 0, 0, 0 ); //remove minutes, seconds, ms
  var time = date.getTime(); //get millisecond time value as key
  a[ date.getTime() ]  = a[ date.getTime() ] || []; 
  a[ date.getTime() ].push( b ); //push the value into array
  return a;
}, {}));
```

```js
var inputArr = [new Date('2017-01-01 17:24'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 17:25'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 18:26'), 
    new Date('2017-01-01 19:27')];

var output = Object.values(inputArr.reduce( function(a,b){
  var date = new Date(b);
  date.setHours( date.getHours(), 0, 0, 0 );
  var time = date.getTime()
  a[ date.getTime() ]  = a[ date.getTime() ] || [];
  a[ date.getTime() ].push( b );
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log( output );
```